# How to use Pinia inside of an npm package?

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I have similar issue [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277755/how-to-publish-an-vue-js-npm-package-with-a-vuex-module), but with Pinia in my case. It's much harder to get Pinia to work outside of Vue components, because of `"Uncaught Error: []: getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?"`, but in this case it is even harder.

Comment: Did you ever manage to work this out, we are getting the exact same issue! :(

Comment: @caveman_dick I decided just not to use it :c

Comment: Any updates? 

I have a problem where I have a form as an npm package which is rather complex due to the requirements with all validations and other logic, so I've decided to use Pinia mostly for the clean structure and not having to pass props all over the place.

Comment: @krcky hello! My packages are for internal use, so my solution wasn't 'clean'. If you are doing something for public use, it may not be appropriate, but what I did is basically passing in active Pinia instance when I initializing my package. I will post some code in the answer section here

Comment: @andrew I'm also using it for private use, storing the npm packages in the GitLab NPM registry. Seeing some code would be perfect, thanks!

Comment: @krcky already there :) Hope it would be useful

Answer (score 2):

Not the cleanest solution, because it requires to have Pinia installed and initialized in the project where your package will be used, but if you're doing this for internal use it is totally okay.

So, in my package it looks like this:

```
    install(app, options = {}) {
        greetings()

        const { $pinia } = options

        if (!$pinia) {
            throw new Error(`No active Pinia instance was passed to your package`)
        }

        let core_store = useCoreStore($pinia)

// moar code
```

And in other project:

```
import MyPackage from '@rusinas/my-package'

app.use(ModernEditor)

const pinia = createPinia()

app.use(MyPackage, { 
    $pinia: pinia
})

app.use(pinia)

app.mount('#app')
```

I noticed that in SPA mode you may not need to provide active pinia to your package, it could figure it out itself, you just need to make sure to `app.use(pinia)` before you initialize you package. But this doesn't work in Nuxt SSR mode, so yeah, this workaround required :(

I think we should raise this question in Pinia's repository. I don't see why it have to work this way. Cases where you need stores outside of setup() are so often and even crucial sometimes for applications, so it should be much easier.

P.S.

Also, keep in mind the possibility of store names collisions. Names should be unique across entire application

P.P.S.

SSR solution:
plugins/MyPackage.plugin.js:

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'

import MyPackage from '@rusinas/my-package'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(MyPackage, {
        $pinia: nuxtApp.$pinia,
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling upon this problem [this](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/2051) might be a helpful source. It uses [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) for bundling.